# How to install tesserocr on windows?

Tags: python, windows-10, tesseract, windows-7-x64

I downloaded executable file of tesseract-OCR and installed it. On the other hand, I also downloaded a zipfile of leptonica from http://www.leptonica.com/download.html. It includes two directory that is `lib` and `include`.

Next I tried to do `pip install tesserocr` in a python virtualenvironment and it returned error

```
 tesserocr.cpp(460) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'leptonica/allheaders.h': No such file or directory
```

I noticed that `allheaders.h` is in `include` directory from the leptonica file I downloaded earlier. How do I solve this? Where should I put the directory `include` and `lib` I got from leptonica to make this work?

Is there any other way to install `tesseract-ocr` and use `tesserocr` properly on windows computer? Currently I am using Windows 10 to run my python script that use tesseract-ocr to recognize some character on image. I also plan to run the script on windows 7 computer later.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Anaconda to install `TesserOCR` in an environment named `OCR`

1. Install Anaconda for Windows from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows)
2. Open Anaconda Prompt:

   `conda create -n OCR python=3.6`

   `activate OCR`
3. For tesseract 3.5.1 (stable):

   `conda install -c simonflueckiger tesserocr`

   **OR** for tesseract 4.0.0 (experimental):

   `conda install -c simonflueckiger/label/tesseract-4.0.0-master tesserocr`

   **OR** download the wheel file matching your Windows platform and Python installation from [here](https://github.com/simonflueckiger/tesserocr-windows_build/releases) and install it via:

   `pip install <path_to_your_wheel_file>`

Comment: I did this but it still has the same error about not having leptonica.

Comment: I did not face this issue but you could try these:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/215#issuecomment-367480562

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling

Answer (score 1):

I know it is too late for you but it might help others.

Installation of leptonica will not be a complete solution at all in order to remove error while installing tesseract-ocr. After the installation of tesseract using windows installer available [here](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki), you should install the python wrapper as:

```
pip install pytesseract
```

Last but not least, you should also set the tesseract path in your script after importing pytesseract library as below (Please do not forget that installation path might be modified in your case!):

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
```

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me perfectly:
Use Anaconda to install TesserOCR in an environment named OCR

```
Install Anaconda for Windows from here

Open Anaconda Prompt:

conda create -n OCR python=2.7

activate OCR

You should install Anaconda and tesserac
```

https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section
and in the prompt command write

```
conda install -c simonflueckiger tesserocr

conda install -c simonflueckiger/label/tesseract-4.0.0-master tesserocr
```

Comment: I did this but it still has the same error about not having leptonica.

Answer (score -2):

Basically,To install any pacakge on windows , go to LIBS location and run the command

```
 "py -3.4 -m pip install SomePackage"
```

for tesseract either follow here : http://emop.tamu.edu/Installing-Tesseract-Windows8

OR

Download set up from here ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract) and double click on set up. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: pytesseract and tesserocr are different