# Installing tesserocr package in Python 3.6.4

Tags: python-3.6

I am using Windows 7, 64 bit and Python 3.6.4 in Spyder |Anaconda custom (64-bit).

Installation Folder of Python:

```
 "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Anaconda3_64\\pythonw.exe"
```

I followed this stackoverflow link to install the package:

"[How to install tesserocr on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405575/how-to-install-tesserocr-on-windows)"

Firstly, I tried this commands in anaconda:

```
  conda create -n OCR python=3.6
  activate OCR
  conda install -c simonflueckiger tesserocr
```

The above command ran without any error, but when I opened my spyder and typed:

```
 import tesserocr
```

It did not work and said `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tesserocr'`

Secondly I tried using .whl file.., it installed perfectly  and import was working fine. However when I ran the below code:

```
import tesserocr
from PIL import Image
print (tesserocr.tesseract_version() ) # print tesseract-ocr version
print (tesserocr.get_languages() ) # prints tessdata path and list of 
  available languages

image = Image.open('C:\\Users\\hack\\Desktop\\Steve.jpeg')
print(image)
print (tesserocr.image_to_text(image) ) # print ocr text from image
```

It gave an message saying:

```
   tesseract 4.00.00alpha
   leptonica-1.75.3 (Mar 24 2018, 15:42:29) [MSC v.1900 LIB Release x64]
   libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 9b : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : 
   libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
```

Path of ocr and language:

```
  ('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\', [])
```

Error:

```
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
```

Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\sitepackages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
        execfile(filename, namespace)

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/hack/Desktop/OCR.py", line 26, in <module>
    print (tesserocr.image_to_text(image) ) # print ocr text from image

  File "tesserocr.pyx", line 2401, in tesserocr._tesserocr.image_to_text

RuntimeError: Failed to init API, possibly an invalid tessdata path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know it's late and hopefully you have already solved it but you need to copy the tessdata folder to wherever your python path leads to