# Running Python scripts in an Anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed Anaconda and through the Anaconda command prompt I installed a package. I want to run a Python script in this Conda environment but when I use cd or ls those commands don't work.

So I tried to next go to git bash (what I normally use to run my Python files), but how do I "activate" this Conda environment while in git bash?

I am basically following this answer: [How to install tesserocr on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405575/how-to-install-tesserocr-on-windows). I got the package installed using Conda but don't know how to run my Python file with that package installed.

When I run Conda in git bash I get the error

```
$ . /c/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
bash: /c/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried going to Anaconda Navigator -> Environments -> Select your environment -> On the "play" symbol select "Open Terminal" (I am using a Mac so I assume something similar exists on Windows)?

Comment: About the Anaconda command prompt, it is not Bash, but rather, a Windows command prompt. So the `ls` command for instance really wouldn't work (it's `dir`). From Git Bash, can you ls into `/c/Anaconda3/etc/profile.d` to check that the conda script is actually there and that Git Bash can see it?

Comment: Anaconda3 is not in my c folder.

Comment: If it's not in your c folder, then that is why you won't be able to run it from Git Bash. I think perhaps you can only run Conda in Windows from the Anaconda prompt, so maybe some more info on which commands you've tried running there and how they failed might help. As I mentioned above, it's a Windows prompt, not Bash, so commands like `ls` are expected not to work.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help. I will just go with the Anaconda prompt.